# Faster way to access namespace variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I have a javascript namespace setup like:

```
(function (skillet, $, undefined) {

  skillet.messages: {

    pages: {

        logon: {

             errors: {
                 username: 'user is wrong'
             }
        } 
    }

  };

} (window.skillet = window.skillet || {}, jQuery));
```

Is there a MORE efficient way of accessing this than constantly typing:

`skillet.messages.pages.logon.errors.username`

when accessing this from other functions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use certain namespace a lot, you could create an alias to it:

```
var shortcut = skillet.messages.pages.logon
shortcut.errors.username
```

Comment: sweet! do you think it's ideal to setup another `shortcuts` type `skillet.shortcuts { logonErrors: skillet.messages.pages.logon.errors }` that can be easily access then like `skillet.shortcuts.logonErrors.username` from anywhere ?

Comment: That's one step further. You could create **alias** under the `skillet` object as long as you don't make too much aliases and result in finding the right alias another problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

Accessing via `skillet.messages.pages.logon.errors.username` will be quick since the prototype chain will not have to be walked. However, if you are using namespaces more than once you could create an alias to it (assign to a local variable):

```
var errors = skillet.messages.pages.logon.errors;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
function getErrors() {
  return skillet.messages.pages.logon.errors;
}

alert( getErrors().username );
```

It works out to be the same thing, really, but your code is a bit cleaner.